# "More than (what) meets the eye"

Tags: grammar, comparatives, relative-clauses

Is it correct to say *more than what meets the eye*? *More than meets the eye* sounds incorrect, but I've seen a lot of people use it and that confuses me. *What* acts like an object to the phrase which otherwise seems incomplete.

Comment: What's grammatically incorrect about "more than meets the eye"?

Comment: the "what" acts like an object to the sentence which otherwise seems incomplete/incorrect.

Comment: Warun, please rewrite your question including all the phrasings of interest in the question itself.  In the current wording, "latter" has no referent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both options are perfectly acceptable. One is a noun-phrase (NP) complement of *than* and the other is a comparative-clause complement. They are structurally equivalent to

1. *there is more than a budget cut*
2. *there is more than was included here*.

In [1], *a budget cut* is an NP complement of *than*. Similarly, *what meets the eye* is also an NP complement of *than*.

(That's all you need to know about that construction, but if you want to unpack it a bit more, *what meets the eye* is like *the thing that meets the eye.* This is an NP with *thing* as its head and a relative clause functioning as a modifier. In the case of *what meets the eye*, the head and the relative are fused: the pronoun *what* functions both as the head of the NP and the subject in a modifying relative clause.)

The other option is *there is more than meets the eye.* In this case, *meets the eye* is a standard comparative clause functioning as complement of *than*. A comparative clause is different from a main clause in that it typically has a gap (e.g., *I'm bigger than* [*she is* _], in which the adjective *big* is gapped out.) The gap in your sentence is in the subject position (i.e., *there is more than* [_ *meets the eye*]) and could be filled by the NP *the budget cut*, for example, if it were a main clause.

Comment: Thank you, that was very elaborate but if both of them are correct, in what situation would you expect me to use either of them?

Comment: There's no grammatical or semantic reason to prefer one over the other, so it would be a stylistic choice. Most people use the shorter version.

Comment: now it makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 3):

Both are grammatical, as others have said. But to me

> "more than meets the eye"

is a perfectly normal expression, while

> "more than what meets the eye"

is something I never recall having heard, and I find it odd — but just because it goes against an established phrase, not for any other reason.

Comment: "What" is odd and goes against the grain because it is not a demonstrative pronoun in modern English.

Comment: It's not demonstrative, it's a sort of relative, and it's normal in other constructions, eg "the same as what I saw". It just isn't customary in this one.

Answer (score -2):

Compare "The book I wrote" with "The book that I wrote".

This belongs to the same category, where the **demonstrative pronoun** can be dropped with no loss in meaning. On the contrary, a gain in elegance (simplicity) is achieved.

"More than **that, which**<sup>1</sup> meets the eye" lacks the simple elegance of "More than meets the eye".

Kind of like **waiting *on* the bus** as opposed to **waiting *for* the bus**. Where, in both cases, the bus is yet to arrive.

But I'll allow that ***what*** may in fact be a suitable alternative standard.

---

<sup>1: Standard modern English would prefer **that, which** to **what** in this case. **More than *what* meets the eye** sounds like a regionalism to me.</sup>

Comment: @Jack Is the note all of that below? Or just those two lines?

Comment: @Alenanno - The note was intended to be just the two lines. The rest (that/what) you see is an afterthought. A post-post scriptum, so-to-speak.

Comment: @JackRobbin I added the note, if I changed something feel free to rollback! :)

Comment: There shouldn't be a comma between "that" and "which". And "what" is much better than "more than that which meets the eye" anyway.

Comment: The comma is moot. However, "more than what meet meets the eye" seems non-standard to me. An import from another language (German?) or some other lack of insight into the separate functions of what and that. "What" may look "better" to a non-native speaker, but to a native speaker of standard modern English it has a foreign ring. The demonstrative pronoun in English should be "that, this, etc.", not "what".

Answer (score -2):

Notwithstanding the grammar-based answers given here indicating that the use 
of *what* is perfectly acceptable in strictly grammatical terms, I would
advise that, in the UK at least, the increasingly common use of *what*
in such circumstances is associated with speakers of lower education.

It’s a matter of style, really. Omitting it is perfectly acceptable
in high and low style.  Including it would diminish you in the eyes
of practictioners of high-style and perhaps critically, devalue the
content of your writing on the basis that, if one cannot express oneself
‘properly’, one’s ideas cannot possibly be of value.  As ever when
writing, you need to consider your audience.  This is perhaps more a
sociological matter than a grammatical one.

Comment: The change from 'the ill-educated' to 'speakers of lower education', loses an essential part of the message.  A person may be among the higher-educated, and still be ill-educated, which is to say that his/her education was of poor quality, even if great in quantity.  'High' English separates the well-educated, that is, those who could afford to pay for a good-quality education in a good, exclusive school, from the ill-educated who were left to the mercy of the state school system.  It is, as I observed, a sociological phenomenon in Britain, not a grammatical one.

Comment: I'm also unclear as to the reasons for the change of 'strict' to 'strictly'.  The adjective is correct in this context in British English; the adverb is not.  Perhaps it is a difference between British English and American English that merely underlines my ironic observation that, from the viewpoint of a well-educated practitioner of 'high' British English, Americans do not, in fact, speak 'proper' English.